# How to write a partially applied function for subtraction specifying the subtrahend?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function that decrements by one -- something like what I would expect `(-1)` to do as a partially applied infix with specified subtrahend. However, written that way `ghc` appears to read the `-` not as a subtraction operator but as a negation.

```
> :t (-1)
(-1) :: Num a => a
```

How can I concisely write a decrement operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use `subtract`, which exists specifically for this purpose:

```
subtract 1
```

Comment: And, in general, there’s `flip`.